¿Por qué cuando cambio de página la pantalla no se ubica en la parte superior?
Estoy realizando un sitio web con ReactJS. Cuando scrolleo en una de las páginas que lo conforman (modificando la posicion en el eje y) como por ejemplo Inicio, y cambio a otra página desde el navbar, por ejemplo Contacto, esta aparece en la misma posición en la que quedó la página Inicio luego de scrollear, en lugar de iniciar en la parte superior de Contacto. Supongamos que scrollee hasta el final de la página Inicio, cuando hago click en Contacto y cambio a esa página, esta se abre en el final en vez de al principio. Es decir, la posicion de la pantalla se está guardando y replicando en todo el sitio en lugar de reiniciarse cuando cambio de página y no logro encontrar por qué ocurre.
Dejo el repo por si acaso: https://github.com/MatiasD1/Pagina.git
Gracias

Pulsa en [edit] y pon el código relevante en la pregunta misma, no a través de enlaces externos. Si el enlace llega a caer, parte fundamental de tu pregunta se perderá. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
